# Android: How to find out how many files are in the internal storage?

Tags: java, android

How to find out how many files there are in the internal storage?

Path:

```
data->user->0->name of your app->files->your files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.filesDir.listFiles()`

edit: once you have that list you have to traverse the tree and count all the files on the way

Comment: Please write that down recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getFilesDir().listFiles().length // delievers the amount of files in the files folder.
```